# AVPlayer Freezes once moved to background

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7, tvos

I have the following code that loads a video and loops it. However, when pressing home and returning to the application the video freezes and will not play again. I feel like the answer is in the AppDelegate functions but can not seem to get them to work.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation



class ViewController: UIViewController, UIApplicationDelegate {



var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
    self.playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
    self.videoPlayer!.play()

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidReachEnd:"), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
}


func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.videoPlayer.play()
}


func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.pause()
}


func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.pause()
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



}
```

Here is what I used to fix it.

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation



class ViewController: UIViewController, UIApplicationDelegate {



var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("video", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

    self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
    self.playerLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
    self.videoPlayer!.play()

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("continueVideo:"), name: "continueVideo", object: nil)


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("playerDidReachEnd:"), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object:nil)
}


func playerDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.videoPlayer.play()
}

func continueVideo(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.videoPlayer.play()
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.pause()
}


func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.pause()
}


func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    videoPlayer.play()
}





override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



}
```

And the app delegate portion

```
import UIKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {


}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {


}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName ("continueVideo", object:nil)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

}


}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple fix, you need to create a `NSNotification` and call it from your `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("continueVideo", object: nil)
}
```

**SWIFT3 Update**

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // NOTE: Notification.Name raw value should be global 
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "com.yourappname.continueVideo"), object:self)
}
```

And the receive that notification in the normal way:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "<funcName>:", name: "continueVideo", object: nil)
```

**SWIFT3 Update**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(<funcName>), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "com.yourappname.continueVideo"), object: nil)
```

Comment: Not really sure what to do with receiving notification? does that go in the view controller? Also is the appdelegate portion in swift?

Comment: You have added a `Notification` in your `ViewDidLoad` already just add this the listener in as well, make sure you create a function and change the selector (highlighted <funcName>)

Comment: You will have a file AppDelegate.swift as standard in the main folder. The `func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication)` should already be there in the file.

Comment: Yes but when I enter in what you typed above it keeps asking for separators. 

should it be more like 
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName ("continueVideo", object:nil)

Comment: Yeah I got it! Thanks so much! ill update my code above for others.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: Sorry I realized what I did! I am currently working on a project that has both swift and obj-c in it! I will update in a mo! It's been a long morning already!!

Comment: No worries. I figured it out. If I wasn't so new at this it wouldn't have been an issue at all. Thanks again for your help and good luck with your project.

Comment: Hi all this has been updated for Swift 3 - Sorry about the post formatting on the `#selector`